# Scholarly sources for the study of numerology in the Old and New Testaments

Tags: old-testament, new-testament, resource-request, numerology

I'm looking for a good scholarly/academic source for the study of numbers and their significance in the Old and New Testaments. I often come across remarks about the Hebrew and/or Christian significance of different numbers, but they are always remarks in passing, and they never seem to provide any sources I can look into further. I would like to be able to substantiate these remarks with some good exposition of the primary sources and rationale for the attribution of various meanings to different numbers in the biblical literature.